# JQuery .bind only works for the first control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-interface

I've read similarly titled questions on here, but the behavior they are experiencing is not quite the same. Please do not link to similar questions, this issue is subtly different if you read carefully.

I have these controls which are created dynamically. They don't have hard-coded IDs.

For each one of these controls, I want a script to fire whenever the value is changed. **The controls are all dropdowns.** Here is my code-behind for when the page is loaded:

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange", "$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_" + param + "').on('change', function(){" + dynamicScript + "});", true);
}
```

The first control which enters this loop works perfectly. If I change the value of the dropdown, the script executes as expected every time. For whichever control enters this loop first, every time I change its dropdown value the script fires and executes perfectly.

However, the other controls do not fire the script. The script is not executed at all when I change the value of the other dropdowns, they do not even attempt to execute the script.

When I debug, I can see that every control is in fact going into this loop, and I can tell that it is the right ID for the control, but no matter what the first control is bound and the others are not. **I also tried "on" and "change" instead of "bind," no difference.**

I'm sure people will want to see the script itself, however the problem can be isolated to the C# code. There is nothing in the JS console, and nothing under the markup on the page in developer tools worth seeing, just a bunch of hard-coded sensitive unrelated information that I obviously cannot share. This problem can be isolated to the C# code, because even if I replace dynamicScript with something very simple (e.g., a simple alert) it only works for the first control.

Comment: Am I to understand that you are creating multiple controls with the same ID? Or is this `[redacted]` replaced _entirely_ with a string and not being used like an attribute selector? Also, if i read it right, your `onChange` function is adding an `onChange` event handler, _not_ a function that it should call `onChange`

Comment: Can you show the output HTML/JS that's rendered at the client?

Comment: "The first control which enters this loop works perfectly."... I'm guessing you are assigning the same ID's to all of them, which won't work (invalid html)--it'll only work on the first.

Comment: @Ted, the controls all have different names/IDs, there are no controls with the same ID obviously.

Comment: @Ted, I should add that I don't think the script is having trouble, it executes and completes successfully when it is fired, it simply isn't being fired for the other controls. I only added it since I figured people would complain if it wasn't provided. I'm not sure I understand the distinction between "adding an onChange event handler" vs. "a function that it should call onChange."

Comment: @Amit, the output unfortunately is not helpful, there is no useful information besides what is provided above.

Comment: @Haleyo - When someone asks for more information, it's usually because it would help him understand the situation. In your case, providing more information could help me (or others) solve _your_ problem. If on the other hand you really do know that there is no useful information in the output, it's probably because you already know the solution.

Comment: @Amit, I have already provided the relevant pieces of output, the rest contains a very large quantity of sensitive information. Perhaps you could glean something useful from it, but it is unlikely, and editing out the sensitive parts would be very tedious. I suspect that the problem is in the code-behind, that I am misunderstanding how this jquery call works since I have never used jquery before.

Comment: @Haleyo - The 1st code fragment in your question is from the server (in asp.net, using c#). The 2nd fragment look like client side JS - _but_ - the client side fragment is not generated from the server fragment (where is the `).on('change` part for example). Without seeing how these things come together, it's impossible to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Amit, I think I may understand the confusion now. I am debugging my coworker's code, what he does is he creates a script dynamically as a string in the C#/.NET server side, if that makes sense. All of this is on the server-side, the whole script is just a string, then he is finding the controls and binding the script to them on change as a string in the C# code. I'm trying to explain, there really isn't anything to see in the HTML/JS output.

Comment: @Haleyo - It's good that you understand my point, but unfortunately you're still avoiding the question. In the end the problem you're describing is on the client side (Right??), so it would help if we could see what the client side code looks like. How it was generated is less important, and only after identifying the problem, a solution can be found. Also try to follow [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78959/discussion-between-haleyo-and-amit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the problem was:

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange", "$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_" + param + "').on('change', function(){" + dynamicScript + "});", true);
}
```

RegisterStartupScript takes 5 parameters, the 3rd parameter is the key. For each event listener I was trying to bind, I was giving the key as "onChange" every time. The key needs to be unique.

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange" + param, "$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_" + param + "').on('change', function(){" + dynamicScript + "});", true);
}
```

I changed

> "onChange"

to

> "onChange" + param

Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer (to clarify my comment), since putting it in a comment would be difficult. If it doesn't solve it, let me know and I'll remove it.

This code:

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange", "$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_" + param + "').on('change', function(){" + dynamicScript + "});", true);
}
```

This part is adding an event listener (listen for change and do something), not a function call (do something on change):

```
"$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_" + param + "').on('change', function(){" + dynamicScript + "});"
```

It should be

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange", dynamicScript, true);
}
```

or

```
foreach (string param in hasDependencies.Keys)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "onChange", "function(){"+dynamicScript+"}", true);
}
```

So that it runs your dynamic script onchange instead of just adding another change event listener.

Does that make sense?

**On a side note** For future reference, writing code like this `$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_[redacted]')` may confuse your issue further for people trying to help, since `[]` can be part of a jQuery selector. If taken literally, that selector would look for an element with an ID of `MainContent_JenkinsField_` that has an attribute named `redacted`. I hope the brackets were just to show where you removed the param, and the real selector looks something like this:`$('#MainContent_JenkinsField_yourParam')`

Comment: I can see how that would be confusing! Yes, your assumption at the end is correct, the [redacted] is meant to indicate that I am censoring the param name. I've never even seen jQuery before yesterday, I didn't realize it was ambiguous. The intention is that it is adding an event listener, so the way it is is correct. The only problem was that I was assigning the same key ("onChange") for each event listener. Problem solved!